# Google WayPoints using list of latitude and longitude

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am referring the [Google Waypoints](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-waypoints) to show show a route from Origin to Destination with multiple stops. But the `Google Waypoint` example using `locations` to show route. But I want to show route from a list of `latitude` and `longitude`.

> My List of Latitude and Longitude (for example)

```
Point A = 26.158700, 91.686940  (Origin)
Point B = 26.158833, 91.688532  (Waypoint)
Point C = 26.159024, 91.690774  (Waypoint)
Point D = 26.159186, 91.693296  (Waypoint)
Point D = 26.159105, 91.696115  (Waypoint)
Point E = 26.159748, 91.695542  (Waypoint)
Point F = 26.160506, 91.695095  (Destination)
```

Please help how can overcome this mess. If you can give me full code for this it will help a lot.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy just pass the (coordinates)values in the required inputs.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/jqvykuLb/1/) Demo

Code Extract

```
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="right-panel">
<div>
<b>Start:</b>
<select id="start">
  <option value="26.158700, 91.686940">Start</option>
</select>
<br>
<b>Waypoints:</b> <br>
<i>(Ctrl+Click or Cmd+Click for multiple selection)</i> <br>
<select multiple id="waypoints">
  <option value="26.158833, 91.688532">B</option>
  <option value="26.159024, 91.690774">C</option>
  <option value="26.159186, 91.693296">D</option>
  <option value="26.159105, 91.696115">E</option>
  <option value="26.159748, 91.695542">F</option>

</select>
<br>
<b>End:</b>
<select id="end">
  <option value="26.160506, 91.695095">Destination</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You are genius buddy. Thank you

Comment: you are welcome, and thanks again